# same column width across tables inside a longtable

Tags: tables, longtable, width

I use many longtables that occupy several pages. These longtables have tables inside that have 1,2 or 3 columns, all of which have the same width: p{2cm}, p{2cm} and p{9.5cm}.

I have been playing around for some time yet I cannot make them of the same width, each table inside the longtable shows a different width. An short example of this is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt] {book}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{booktabs,longtable,rotating} 
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document} 

\newcommand{\subTableOne}[8]{%
\begin{tabular}{ @{\extracolsep{\fill}} | p{2cm - 2\tabcolsep - 1.25\arrayrulewidth}  |  p{2cm - 2\tabcolsep - 1.25\arrayrulewidth} |  p{9.5cm - 2\tabcolsep - 1.25\arrayrulewidth} | @{}}
\hline
  \multicolumn{3}{| p{13.5cm} |}{ }\\
  \multicolumn{3}{| c |}{ #1 }\\
  \multicolumn{3}{| c |}{ }\\
\hline
  Name: & \multicolumn{2}{ c |}{ #2 } \\
  Description: & \multicolumn{2}{ c |}{ #3 } \\
\hline
\hline
  \multicolumn{3}{| c |}{\multirow{2}{*} { Some title } } \\
  \multicolumn{3}{| c |}{ } \\
\hline
  \parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{2}{*}{\parbox{2cm}{Some \\ part:}}} & Type: & #3 \\
  \cline{2-3}
  & Size: & #4  \\
  \hline

  \parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\parbox{2cm}{Other \\ part:}}}} & Domain: & #5 \\
  \cline{2-3}
  & Size: & #6 \\
  \cline{2-3}
  & Distribution: & #7  \\

\hline
\end{tabular}%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand{\subSubtableInt}[1]{ % elems
\clist_map_inline:nn { #1 } { & \multicolumn{2}{ p{13.5cm - 4\tabcolsep - 2.5\arrayrulewidth} |}{ ##1} \\  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand{\subSubtable}[3]{
\hline
\parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{\clist_count:n {#3}}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\parbox{2cm}{#1}}}} & \multicolumn{2}{ p{13.5cm - 4\tabcolsep - 2.5\arrayrulewidth} |}{ #2 } \\
\subSubtableInt{#3}
& \multicolumn{2}{ p{13.5cm - 4\tabcolsep - 2.5\arrayrulewidth} |}{   } \\
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\subTableTwo}[8]{%
\begin{tabular}{ @{\extracolsep{\fill}} | p{2cm - 2\tabcolsep - 1.25\arrayrulewidth}  |  p{2cm - 2\tabcolsep - 1.25\arrayrulewidth} |  p{9.5cm - 2\tabcolsep - 1.25\arrayrulewidth} | @{}}
\hline
  \multicolumn{3}{| c |}{\multirow{2}{*}{ Another title } } \\
  \multicolumn{3}{| c |}{ } \\

\hline
  Cat.1: & \multicolumn{2}{ p{11.5cm - 4\tabcolsep - 2.5\arrayrulewidth} |}{ #1 } \\

\hline
  Cat.2: & \multicolumn{2}{ p{11.5cm - 4\tabcolsep - 2.5\arrayrulewidth} |}{ #2 } \\

\subSubtable{Sub.1}{#3}{#4}
\subSubtable{Sub.2}{#5}{#6}
\subSubtable{Sub.3}{#7}{#8}

\hline
\end{tabular}%
 }

\setlength\tabcolsep{1.5pt} % default value: 6pt

\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l@{}} %{@{}l@{}}

\caption{Longtable with subtables.} \\

\subTableOne{Main title}{the name}{a description}{category of the problem}{problem size}{detailed description}{estimation of size}{distribution} \\

\subTableTwo{comment}{another comment}{\# 1}{\# 2, \# 3, \ldots}{\# 1}{\# 2, \# 3, \# 4, \ldots}{\# 1}{\# 2, \# 3, \# 4, \ldots} \\

\label{tab:test1}

\end{longtable}


\end{document}
```

This renders as:

[image: the latex result]

Any idea how to properly do this?

Comment: Each of your subtables is treated as a single (unbreakable) entry in the longtable.  The only thing the longtable is doing here is allowing you to add captions, which could be done using \def\@captype{table} or \captionof{table}{...}.

Comment: @Kormylo: Another advantage of nesting the tables in the longtable is that their order is not rearranged by LaTeX according to space. In any case, do you understand why even though the tables have the same column definition, they have different width?

Comment: \multicol can also add space.